# Updating radio button field on JIRA using Python

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to update radio button fields in JIRA using python logic by building a dictionary. After I built the dictionary, when I try to create issue in JIRA, I am getting an error message -

```
'customfield_10543': "Option id 'null' is not valid"}
```

Python logic:

```
options = ['10461','10462']
new_issues = []
new_issue = {
                    'project': {"key":"Test"},
                    'summary': 'Test Summary',
                    'description': 'Test issue by Jira Integration'
)

if df.having_pet.iloc[i] == 'YES':
   new_issue[having_pet] = {'value':options[0]}
if df.having_pet.iloc[i] == 'NO':
   new_issue[having_pet] = {'value':options[1]}
new_issues.append(new_issue)
jira.create_issues(field_list=new_issues)
```

HTML component from Chrome Inspector:

```
<input class="radio" id="customfield_10543-1" name="customfield_10543" type="radio" value="10461" resolved="">
<label for="customfield_10543-1">
Yes
</label>
<input checked="checked" class="radio" id="customfield_10543-2" name="customfield_10543" type="radio" value="10462" resolved="">
<label for="customfield_10543-2">
No
</label>
```

Please advise how to update the radio button on JIRA based on dataframe that i have.